# SVG text (with tspans) vertical offset

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to draw a rectangle around a `<text>` with mutliple `<tspans>` (each with `dy=1em`) in it.

I am using `textElement.getBoundingClientRect()` to find the size of the text, and then update the attributes of my `rect` accordingly. The issue that I am facing is the vertical offset of the `<text>` element itself:

[image: weird offset]

This seems to be present regardless of what `alignment-baseline` I am using (`middle` in the example below).

Here is what the code looks like:

```js
var translate = function(x, y) {
  return 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')';
};

var bbox = d3.select('#stuff')
  .node().getBoundingClientRect();
d3.select('#text-container').append('rect')
  .attr({
    width: bbox.width,
    height: bbox.height
  });
d3.select('#stuff').attr('transform',
  translate(bbox.width / 2, 0)
);
d3.select('#middle').attr('transform',
  translate(0, (bbox.height / 2))
).attr('x2', bbox.width);
```

```css
text {
  alignment-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
#text-container rect {
  fill: red;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
tspan {
  alignment-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-size: 20;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width='400' height='900'>
  <g transform='translate(100,100)' id='text-container'>
    <circle cx=0 cy=0 r=3 fill="red"></circle>
    <line x1=0 x2=100 y1=0 y2=0 stroke="green" id="middle"></line>
    <text id='stuff'>
      <tspan dy=1em x=0>where</tspan>
      <tspan dy=1em x=0>is</tspan>
      <tspan dy=1em x=0>this</tspan>
      <tspan dy=1em x=0>offset</tspan>
      <tspan dy=1em x=0>coming</tspan>
      <tspan dy=1em x=0>from?</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
<p id="info"></p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: According to @Klaujesi's answer, the required offset can be found by using `textElement.getBBox().y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getBBox:

```
var bbox = text.node().getBBox();
```

Look at this sample: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1160929. Mike use .getBBox (get boundary box)

Here the fiddle with your working code: https://jsfiddle.net/dm9du4L6/

Comment: check the jsFiddle